# How can I run a script in Google Drive, which is in G: drive from Python, which is installed in C: drive (Windows 10)?

Tags: python, windows, google-drive-shared-drive

I have a shared .py script stored in a shared folder in google drive, which for our work machines is mounted on G:. It needs to be run using python, which is installed on C:.

I can see G: in file explorer, however I cannot cd to it from command prompt and I do not think I run the script using python "path-to-script.py" if the script is in a different drive, although I am happy to be proven wrong here.

Is there a way I can let local Python installs access this shared folder? Unfortunately, using git instead of Google Drive is not an option.

Here's what my command prompt would normally look like when I run a script:

```
C:WINDOWS\System32> python ~\scripts\shared_scripts.py
```

But since the script lives in G:, not C:, I can't navigate to its location. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Do you mean `G:` and `C:` (instead of `:G` and `:C`)? Also, please provide a [mre] that shows exactly what you do.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, `~` has no meaning on Windows, while on Linux it refers to the user directory. What do you think `python ~\scripts\shared_scripts.py` should do? What do you mean with _"But since the script lives in G:, not C:, I can't navigate to its location"_? Enter `G:` in the command prompt and you will go to that drive, or use `python G:\path\to\your\script.py`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Sorry, I'm a linux user and a bit rusty on windows. Thanks, I'll give that a go I was trying "cd G:" with no luck.
In theory will a C: installed python environment be able to run a script in G:?

Comment: It doesn't matter where python is installed. I can run scripts located on a USB disk, for example. What specific errors are you getting when trying to navigate to the G drive or even give the full path to the file, starting with G:\?

Comment: @OneCricketeer. I didn't get that far, I wasn't aware I could navigate to G:. Now I know that's possible, I'll try again and hopefully should be okay. Thanks.